# Creatig custom end() iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I have to create class Iterator, itering sequence in a vector to complete a task, but in task is used range-based for loop like:

```
for (T element: sequence) {
    std::cout << element << " ";
    std::cin >> numToGenerate;
    sequence.generateNext(numToGenerate);
}
```

So I should create my own Sequence and Iterator classes which can do the task, but I can not figure out how to do my end() iterator.

Here is my code till now:

```
template<typename T, typename Generator>
class Sequence
{
std::vector<T> elements;
Generator generator;

public:
class Iterator
{
public:
    int index;
    std::vector<T>& elements;

    Iterator(int index, std::vector<T>& elements) : index(index), elements(elements) {};

    void operator++()
    {
        this->index++;
    }

    T operator*()
    {
        return this->elements[this->index];
    }

    bool operator!= ( Iterator other)
    {
        return this->index != other.index;
    }
};

void generateNext(int numToGenerate)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numToGenerate; i++)
    {
        T next = generator();
        elements.push_back(next);
    }
}

Iterator begin()  
{
    return Iterator(0, elements);
}

Iterator end() 
{
    //??????????
}
};
```

Comment: btw its not clear why you implemented your own iterator, from the code you show here is seems lie `std::vector::iterator` does already all you need

Comment: If the sequence is expanded when being iterated over, std::vector iterator won't work: it will be invalidated when std::vector reallocates.

Comment: true, though you still have to be carefull when inserting anywhere but at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can create the end iterator pointing to one position beyond the last element from your vector, just like how the 'std::vector''s iterator does.

```
Iterator end()  
{
    return Iterator(elements.size(), elements);
}
```

As an alternative, you could just use `std::vector::iterator`, and create wrapper `begin` and `end` methods for it.

Comment: It is problem because the sequence is changing its size while itering

Comment: If you are referring to insertions while iterating, that would not cause any problems if you do not cache the result of `end()`, because each time you call it will get the updated size of the underlying vector.

Comment: If the sequence is expanded when being iterated over, `std::vector` iterator won't work: it will be invalidated when `std::vector` reallocates.

Comment: That is my problem. Ad I have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I find your motivation rather questionable. Why do you want to push elements to the end **while** iterating over the elements?

Your `generateNext` does not depend on the index. No matter at what index you are, you always push at the end (meaning your `Generator` would have to remember what elements it already produced, ie keep an index, isnt this what the sequnce is supposed to do?).

Assuming your loop as written works, it can only end if the user types several times `0` until the sequence reaches the end. The natural way to insert element into your sequence is what you implemented in `generateNext`. Why you want to intervene that with iterating over the sequence is not clear to me.

Anyhow, your loop can be made working if you make the comparsion to the `end` iterator special (I left out the `Generator` for the sake of brevity):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct Sequence {
    std::vector<T> elements;
    struct Iterator {
        int index;
        std::vector<T>& elements;
        bool isEnd;
        Iterator(int index, std::vector<T>& elements,bool isEnd=false)
            : index(index), elements(elements) {};
        void operator++() { this->index++; }
        T operator*() { return this->elements[this->index]; }
        bool operator!= (const Iterator& other) {
            if (other.isEnd) return index != elements.size();
            return this->index != other.index;
        }
    };
    void generateNext(int numToGenerate) {
        static int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numToGenerate; i++) { elements.push_back(counter+i); }
        counter += numToGenerate + 100;
    }
    Iterator begin() { return Iterator(0, elements); }
    Iterator end() { return Iterator(0,elements,true); }
};
```

Now you can use the range based for loop:

```
int main() {
    Sequence<int> s;
    s.generateNext(5);
    for (auto element : s) {
        if (element <3) s.generateNext(3);
    }
    for (auto element : s) { std::cout << element << " ";}
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 105 106 107 208 209 210 311 312 313
```

Note that I specifically chose the "generator" such that you can see where in the loop the numbers are generated. Is this really what you want? Let me ask again: Why would you generate your sequnce in that way? Consider how the vector is filled:

```
first iteration:  0 1 2 3 4 105 106 107
                  ^--------------------this one would be printed in your loop
second iteration: 0 1 2 3 4 105 106 107 208 209 210
                    ^
third iteration:  0 1 2 3 4 105 106 107 208 209 210 311 312 313 
                      ^
and then some more iterations where we dont add elements to eventually reach the end
```

**Bottomline:** I strongly recommend you to rethink your design. `for` loops typically indicate that you know before-hand how many iterations have to be done. Using iterators typically helps to be independent of the container type, but inside your loop you actually do use the container not the iterator. `end` iterators are "fragile" in general, because if you push something then even without reallocation what was `end` before now isnt anymore.

**TL;DR:** use a while-loop instead, something along the line of:

```
sequence s;
generator g;
while (g.has_more()) s.push_back(g());
```

Comment: See my answer to get more light about the task, given to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
include <iostream>

#include "Sequence.h"

class IntegersGenerator {
int last;
public:
IntegersGenerator() : last(0) {}

int operator()() {
    return this->last++;
}
};

class FibonacciGenerator{
int last;
int current;
public:
FibonacciGenerator() : last(0), current(0) {}

int operator()() {
    if (this->current == 0 && this->last == 0) {
        this->last = 1;
        return 0;
    }

    int next = this->last + this->current;
    this->last = this->current;
    this->current = next;

    return next;
}
};

template<typename T, typename Generator>
void readGenerateWrite() {
Sequence<T, Generator> sequence;

int numToGenerate;
std::cin >> numToGenerate;
sequence.generateNext(numToGenerate);

for (T element : sequence) {
    std::cout << element << " ";
    std::cin >> numToGenerate;
    sequence.generateNext(numToGenerate);
}
}

int main() {
char generatorType;
std::cin >> generatorType;
if (generatorType == 'i') {
    readGenerateWrite<int, IntegersGenerator>();
}
else if (generatorType == 'f') {
    readGenerateWrite<int, FibonacciGenerator>();
}

return 0;
}
```

That is the code given to me with the task, which I can not change.
and Example: 
Input:
i
3 1 1 0 2 0 0 0
Output:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6

Answer (score 0):

I was gives exactly the same task this week and your code helped me a lot. You have probably already solved the task but I figured out that it doesn't matter what the end() returns - it can be the same as begin() or anything that compiles successfully. The key to the task is overloading operator != so it gets the new vector size each cycle. I did it by comparing the variable index with the size.

```
 bool operator!= ( Iterator other)
{

    return this->index != elements.size();
}
```